# How to remove trailing empty space from a field

Tags: mysql

I ran into the problem that some fields within a table have a trailing empty space. The only way that i can think of how to remove them is to export it with CSV and do it with Excel which is a bit of a hassle. How can i do this through pure sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select RTRIM(yourcolumn)
FROM yourtable;
```

You can use [`RTRM()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rtrim-function.php).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

```
    UPDATE table SET field=TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM field) WHERE field LIKE '% '
```

For more info about the TRIM function, check http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php